# Issue with a d3 line chart using a csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm new to this d3 (and to be fair programming in general). Due to this I have been trying to twist other peoples examples to what I am after (which is hopefully a fairly straightforward line chart). I have been looking at the example here:

http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/4175202

I would like the functionality of being able to switch what series I am charting (as well as what variable I am charting, but I am hoping the null values in my .csv will restrict this) along with the highlighting of the line when the mouse goes over it. I have therefore tried to take out the bits that refer to the selecting of groups and changed the drop down menu to match the csv, in the hope this would work - it didn't.

My html and csv file are below and any help or pointers you lovely people could give me would be most welcoming

Can I also check my assumption that having null amounts in the columns will mean that the variable won't be charted for the breakdowns that are not relevent.

Thank you all in advance

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Starts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 7px;
}

.country {opacity: 0.3;}
.country:hover {opacity:1;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="menu"><b>Starts</b><br>Select series: <select>
    <option value="TOT">Total</option>
    <option value="AREA">Area</option>
    <option value="AGE">Age</option>
    <option value="SEX">Gender</option></select>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        w = 660 - margin.left - margin.right,
        h = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        x = d3.time.scale().range([0, w]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0]);
        parseDate = d3.time.format("%b-&y").parse;

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

 var countries,
transpose;


    var line = d3.svg.line()
       .interpolate("basis")
       .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
       .y(function(d) { return y(d.stat); });


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
       svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "x axis");


    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");


    var menu = d3.select("#menu select")
    .on("change", change);   


d3.csv("data.csv", function(csv) {
        countries = csv;
        redraw();
    });

d3.select(window)
    .on("keydown", function() { altKey = d3.event.altKey; })
    .on("keyup", function() { altKey = false; });

var altKey;


function change() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  d3.transition()
      .duration(altKey ? 7500 : 1500)
      .each(redraw);
}


function redraw() {


    var nested = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.indicatorCode; })
        .map(countries)

    var series = menu.property("value");


    var data = nested[series];

    var keyring = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
             return (key !== "indicatorName" && key !== "monthCode" && key !== "indicatorCode" && key !== "month");
         });

     var transpose = keyring.map(function(name) {
            return {
              name: name,
              values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {month: parseDate(d.month), stat: +d[name]};
              })
            };
        });


    x.domain([
    d3.min(transpose, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.month; }); }),
    d3.max(transpose, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.month; }); })
  ]);

    y.domain([
    d3.min(transpose, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.stat; }); }),
    d3.max(transpose, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.stat; }); })
  ]);

    var country = svg.selectAll(".country")
      .data(transpose);


    var countryEnter = country.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.name; });


    countryEnter.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });


    countryEnter.append("text")
     .attr("class", "names")
     .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.month) + "," + y(d.value.stat) + ")"; })
     .attr("x", 4)
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


    var countryUpdate = d3.transition(country);

    countryUpdate.select("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

    countryUpdate.select("text")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.values[d.values.length - 1].month) + "," + y(d.values[d.values.length - 1].stat) + ")"; });


      d3.transition(svg).select(".y.axis")
          .call(yAxis);  

      d3.transition(svg).select(".x.axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

}

var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  menu.property("value", "SEX").node().focus();
  change();
}, 7000);


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**data.csv**

```
indicatorName,indicatorCode,month,monthCode,Total,Area1,Area2,Area2,Area4,Youngster,Middle aged,Elderly,Male,Female
Total,TOT,2011/05,MthMay11,22,,,,,,,,,
Total,TOT,2011/06,MthJun11,49,,,,,,,,,
Total,TOT,2011/07,MthJul11,489,,,,,,,,,
Total,TOT,2011/08,MthAug11,1002,,,,,,,,,
Total,TOT,2011/09,MthSep11,3097,,,,,,,,,
Area,AREA,2011/05,MthMay11,,22,,,,,,,,
Area,AREA,2011/06,MthJun11,,24,11,7,7,,,,,
Area,AREA,2011/07,MthJul11,,167,248,68,6,,,,,
Area,AREA,2011/08,MthAug11,,500,390,210,260,,,,,
Area,AREA,2011/09,MthSep11,,590,580,390,540,,,,,
Age,AGE,2011/05,MthMay11,,,,,,19,3,,,
Age,AGE,2011/06,MthJun11,,,,,,21,12,16,,
Age,AGE,2011/07,MthJul11,,,,,,110,89,290,,
Age,AGE,2011/08,MthAug11,,,,,,143,144,715,,
Age,AGE,2011/09,MthSep11,,,,,,472,615,2010,,
Gender,SEX,2011/05,MthMay11,,,,,,,,,11,11
Gender,SEX,2011/06,MthJun11,,,,,,,,,24,25
Gender,SEX,2011/07,MthJul11,,,,,,,,,244,245
Gender,SEX,2011/08,MthAug11,,,,,,,,,508,494
Gender,SEX,2011/09,MthSep11,,,,,,,,,1787,1310
```

**simpleline.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>

body {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}

#chart1 svg {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
/*
  margin: 50px;
  Minimum height and width is a good idea to prevent negative SVG dimensions...
  For example width should be =< margin.left + margin.right + 1,
  of course 1 pixel for the entire chart would not be very useful, BUT should not have errors
*/

}
#chart1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
</style>
<body class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>

<div id="chart1" >
  <svg style="height: 500px;"></svg>
</div>

<script src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="utils.js"></script>
<script src="interactiveLayer.js"></script>
<script src="legend.js"></script>
<script src="axis.js"></script>
<script src="scatter.js"></script>
<script src="line.js"></script>
<script src="lineChart.js"></script>

<script>
// Wrapping in nv.addGraph allows for '0 timeout render', stores rendered charts in nv.graphs, and may do more in the future... it's NOT required
var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.lineChart()
  .options({
    margin: {left: 100, bottom: 100},
    showXAxis: true,
    showYAxis: true,
    transitionDuration: 250
  })
  ;

  // chart sub-models (ie. xAxis, yAxis, etc) when accessed directly, return themselves, not the parent chart, so need to chain separately
  chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel("Month")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b'));

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('Number')
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'))
    ;

  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(sinAndCos())
    .call(chart);

  //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  //nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart1 svg').call(chart) });

  chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

  return chart;
});

function sinAndCos() {
var tot= [{x:new Date("May 31, 2013"), y:200}, {x:new Date("June 30, 2013"), y:500}, {x:new Date("July 31, 2013"), y:1600}, {x:new Date("August 31, 2013"), y:2700}, {x:new Date("September 31, 2013"), y:3800}],
    Age1= [{x:new Date("May 31, 2013"), y:200}, {x:new Date("June 30, 2013"), y:350}, {x:new Date("July 31, 2013"), y:1200}, {x:new Date("August 31, 2013"), y:2200}, {x:new Date("September 31, 2013"), y:2900}],
    Age2= [{x:new Date("May 31, 2013"), y:0}, {x:new Date("June 30, 2013"), y:100}, {x:new Date("July 31, 2013"), y:300}, {x:new Date("August 31, 2013"), y:400}, {x:new Date("September 31, 2013"), y:600}],
    Age3= [{x:new Date("May 31, 2013"), y:0}, {x:new Date("June 30, 2013"), y:50}, {x:new Date("July 31, 2013"), y:100}, {x:new Date("August 31, 2013"), y:100}, {x:new Date("September 31, 2013"), y:300}]
        ;

      return [
        {
          values: tot,
          key: "Total",
          color: "#ff7f0e"
        },
        {
          values: Age1,
          key: "Youngster",
          color: "#2ca02c"
        },
        {
          values: Age2,
          key: "Middle Aged",
          color: "#2222ff"
        }
        ,
        {
          values: Age3,
          key: "Old Person",
          color: "#667711"
        }
      ];
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Have you seen [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/)? There should be a chart there that does what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Lars. I have been looking through the website and found some nice visualisations. I downloaded the master zip file and after getting the simple line chart to work I started to try and modify it. After modifying the .html to take in my data I seem to lose the charts axis and all functionality (I do at least get the lines though). Could this be as I am trying to use months rather than numbers? Apologies again but I am still trying to get to grips with this. I have added the altered .html to the post if you could give me any pointers I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: You need to parse the dates, i.e. something like `x: d3.format("%m %Y").parse("05 2013")`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff. Thank you again for your help and apologies for continuing to ask questions but I added the example line from above to the var statements (GB, Age1, Age2, Age3) in the function sinandCos instead of the new Date("May 31, 2013") and it is still failing. Sorry but I am really stuck, was that where I should be adding the parse?

Comment: Have a look at the other NVD3 examples. There's quite a few that use CSV data which I think will be more suitable for you.